# Align images in a box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104187515/CASE%20OEPN/Game.html
Demo showcasihg issue above

As you can see when you use it the images don't align in the box and sometimes 2 images can be in the box.

i have all the images in al ul class called slot (don't know if that will help?)

Would it be possible to make the images align?

Im following this tutorial:  http://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html

if you need my to supply more information or code you can just ask.

Extra info:

all images are 145x145px

Thanks

This is where the images are stored they are then cycled through and shown

```
<br>
<div class="fancy">
    <ul class="slot">
        <li><img src="Knife.png"></li>
        <li><img src="SSG 08.png"></li>
        <li><img src="P2000.png"></li>
        <li><img src="UMP-45.png"></li>
        <li><img src="PP-Bizon.png"></li>
        <li><img src="P250.png"></li>
        <li><img src="P90.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Nova.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Negev.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Mp7.png"></li>
        <li><img src="PP-Bizon.png"></li>
        <li><img src="P250.png"></li>
        <li><img src="P90.png"></li>
        <li><img src="M4A1-S.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Gock-18.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Five-SeveN.png"></li>
        <li><img src="Desert Eagle.png"></li>
        <li><img src="CZ75-Auto.png"></li>
```

And that continues adding more images

Comment: You should probably put the relevant code here as a working snippet.

Comment: What code do you think would be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error. I marked it in the code:

```
onStart : function() {
    $('.slot').removeClass('winner');
    audio.play();  // <-- ReferenceError: audio is not defined
    Money = Money + 2.50
    document.getElementById('Money').innerHTML = Money;
},
```

If you comment that line out, it will work.

Btw, it's a good idea to view the javascript console in your browser and watch for error messages.

Edit:
Also, some of your images may not be 145x145, because if you force it with css, everything snaps into place.

```
.fancy .slot li img {
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
}
```

Edit2:
You also have a `Mixed Content` error, because your page url is `https`, but you requesting jquery over `http`. Change your jquery script tag `src` to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js`.

Comment: The images in the slot machine are still cut off...

Comment: I edited it have a look now. I'm still having issues. That dropbox link isn't a download you can veiw the game

Comment: The images still get chopped off. when you spin are they chopped off for you?

Comment: It does work... I forgot the curly brace :(